# How to get the number of invocations of void function?

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I'm trying to write a test to count a total of invocations of the `ngAfterViewInit()` function. 
I'm testing my directive which only has a `ngAfterViewInit()` function.

```
it('myDirective is working', () => {    
  expect(myDirective.calls.count()).toEqual(2);
});
```

In the last line of the test, I'm trying to call the `calls` property on the `ngAfterViewInit()` function, but there is an error:

> Property calls does not exists on type '() => void'.

Comment: Did you try `expect(myDirective.ngAfterViewInit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if ngAfterViewInit was called twice by using the following code:

```
expect(myDirective.ngAfterViewInit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
```

The `calls` property is available on `myDirective.ngAfterViewInit` after you call `spyOn(myDirective, 'ngAfterViewInit')`. It's not available on `myDirective` itself.